# MySQL count from intermediary table

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm trying to find the most used categories in an intermediary table which contains two ids, I'm running this to find all the counts of posts against categories.

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM category WHERE category_name ORDER BY category_name');

foreach($data as $row) {

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(p_id) FROM p_categories c,category ca WHERE c.category_id = ca.category_id AND category_name = :category_name";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':category_name' => $row['category_name']));
$catco = $q->fetch();

echo '<p>'.$row['category_name'].' ('.$catco[0].')</p>';
}
```

This returns all the categories, but I want to limit it to only the top four categories having most p_id. I tried limiting the count query to 4 but that didn't work.

Here are the tables:

posts: p_id, p_name

p_categories: p_id, category_id

category: category_id, category_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single query

```
$sql = "SELECT p_categories.category_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt, category.category_name
        FROM p_categories 
        LEFT JOIN category
        ON p_categories.category_id = category.id 
        GROUP BY `category_id` 
        ORDER BY cnt 
        DESC LIMIT 4"

$data = $conn->query($sql); 
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['category_name'].' ('.$row['cnt'] .')</p>';
}
```